# DOMPDF does not change the font in the resulting PDF

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, dompdf

I have a problem when I try to change the default font.
The symbols in resulting PDF are changed by ??? symbols, so I tried to change the default font.
But when I try to change the default font in vendor/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/config/dompdf.php `"default_font" => "courier"`
the font in the resulting PDF is not changed - Helvetica stays whatever I did.
I even tried to change the default font in the controller just before PDF generation:
    `PDF::setOptions(['dpi' => 150, 'defaultFont' => 'courier']);`
but, it did not help also.

What could be the problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to check your css file.

```php
$pdf->setOption(['dpi' => 150, 'defaultFont' => 'mohanonda']);
```

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'your_font_name';
    src: url('your_font_location.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

```php
<p style="font-family: 'your_font_name', sans-serif;">ID Number : {{ $data['name'] }}</p>
```

you can get solution using this. but it has one another problem multiple language not support in hear.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: Please also revisit your formatting for the sake of readability.